# Static variable mysteriously being set to nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, static

I'm in XCode 6.1.1 and iOS 8.1

For some bizarre reason that I can't seem to locate, I have a static variable that is being set to nil AFTER it receives a legit value.

I have a class like so...

```
@implementation MyCustomViewController
{
}

static SomeObject *someObject;

+(SomeObject *)someObject
{
    return someObject;
}

+(void)setSomeObject:(SomeObject *)obj
{
    someObject = obj;
}
```

And I have breakpoints set on these methods, and as best I can tell, somehow, during the transition to displaying this view controller, the `someObject` is being set to nil without hitting my breakpoint.

Any ideas how or why this would happen?

The class `MyCustomViewController` never goes out of existence before, during, or after, the transition where this variable is mysteriously going nil.

Comment: YES the project is using Arc

Comment: This is strange behavior at a glance, have you tried setting a Watch point on the variable? You could trace what's writing to that memory location.

Comment: No I haven't tried a watchpoint from LLDB, just breakpoints from XCode. Do you think a watchpoint would be more effective?

Comment: You can halt execution when the variable is modified, so yeah.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87210/discussion-between-nighthawk441-and-user3055655).